# TypeInitializationException: Static class constructor throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I use a **static** helper class with **static readonly** and **const members** in one of the `Awake()` methods in my **Unity3D** application:

```
var localPosition = TileConstants.SideCenters[direction];

...

public static class TileConstants
{
    public static readonly Vector3[] SideCenters = new Vector3[]
    {
        (Vertices[0] + Vertices[5]) / 2f,
        (Vertices[1] + Vertices[0]) / 2f,
        (Vertices[2] + Vertices[1]) / 2f,
        (Vertices[3] + Vertices[2]) / 2f,
        (Vertices[4] + Vertices[3]) / 2f,
        (Vertices[5] + Vertices[4]) / 2f
    };

    private static readonly Vector3[] Vertices = new Vector3[]
    {
        new Vector3( Cos60, 0f,  Cos30),
        new Vector3( 1f,    0f,  0f),
        new Vector3( Cos60, 0f, -Cos30),
        new Vector3(-Cos60, 0f, -Cos30),
        new Vector3(-1,     0f,  0f),
        new Vector3(-Cos60, 0f,  Cos30)
    };

    public const float TileWidth = Sqrt3 * TileVerticeRadius;
    public const float TileHeight = 2 * TileVerticeRadius;
    public const float TileVerticeRadius = 1f;

    private const float Cos30 = Sqrt3 / 2f;
    private const float Cos60 = 0.5f;
    private const float Sqrt3 = 1.7320508075688f;
}
```

*(I use const where I can because it's compile time... but sadly I can't do that with Vector3-s.)*

But it throws this exception:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
TileConstants..cctor () (at TileConstants.cs:7)
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'TileConstants' threw an exception.
TileVisuals.Awake () (at TileVisuals.cs:32)
```

Comment: Maybe use an actual static constructor to instantiate those? Initialization (and this may be an implementation detail so don't rely on it) usually goes top->bottom in the list of variables, so Vertices should come before SideCenters. Either way, use an actual static constructor method so you have full control.

Comment: Initializers are run in lexical order. This means `SideCenters` cannot (safely) refer to `Vertices`. While you can "fix" this by reordering the definitions, relying on this is a bad idea to begin with, and being explicit in a constructor is a better idea.

Comment: Oh, why didn't I realised this. Thanks guys!